# Некорректная работа if и switch

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть поле объекта класса `Player` - `isGround`, всё проверил, значение меняется, но используя переменную в `if`, в конструкции `switch` - `case` он будто бы не обращает внимания, в чем ошибка?

```
void Move(Player& pl)
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        char a = _getche();
        switch (a)
        {
        case 'a':
            pl.point_y = pl.point_y - 1;
            break;
        case 'd':
            pl.point_y = pl.point_y + 1;
            break;
        case 's':
            pl.point_x = pl.point_x + 1;
            break;
            if (pl.isGround == true)
            {
            case ' ':
                pl.point_x = pl.point_x - pl.jumpforce;
                cout << "JUMP" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    pl.ChangePositiont('$');
}
```

Comment: чтобы ответить надо посмотреть код *перед* этим **if**-ом. Покажите свой **switch** поподробнее.

Comment: Сделал правки в вопросе

Comment: `if (pl.isGround == true)` никогда не выполнится. При пробеле сразу идёт код в `case ' '`

Comment: Перенесите `if` внутрь `case`, переход после `switch` идет прямо в `case`.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ автора конечно имеет право на жизнь, однако такой код будет более корректен и читабелен в данной ситуации (по рекомендации Harry в комментариях)

```
void Move(Player& pl)
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        char a = _getche();
        switch (a)
        {
        case 'a':
            pl.point_y = pl.point_y - 1;
            break;
        case 'd':
            pl.point_y = pl.point_y + 1;
            break;
        case 's':
            pl.point_x = pl.point_x + 1;
            break;
        case ' ': 
            if (pl.isGround == true)
            {
                pl.point_x = pl.point_x - pl.jumpforce;
                cout << "JUMP" << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    pl.ChangePositiont('$');
}
```